# Jenkins: Forcing the master branch of a git repo

Tags: git, jenkins

A build for Jenkins is somehow triggered by commits to a non-master branch, which will then be  deployed instead of the master.

Is there a way to force the master build only?

Comment: Is it possible that not specifying the GIT_BRANCH env variable will cause this behavior?

Comment: yes, when you don't specify a branch, it builds each branch. try creating build jobs / per branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the [git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) you can define which branches you want the jenkins to build.

[image]